# В какой области памяти создаются переменные типов, допускающие пустые значения

Tags: c#

Помогите разобраться.

В книге написано:

> Типы, допускающие пустые значения, фактически являются ссылочными
>   типами, и переменные этих типов создаются в динамической памяти". Но
>   если мы говорим о ссылочных типах, то переменные с адресом на объект
>   хранятся же в стеке, а сами объекты в куче.

Почему тогда здесь говорится, что переменные создаются в динамической памяти.

В книге ошибка или я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это не ошибка, это утверждение, далекое от реальности + кривой перевод.

Есть типы значений (value types), есть ссылочные типы (reference types).

Переменная value type хранит значение прямо в себе. Для value type после `a = b` вы получите "в `a` лежит то же значение, что и в `b`". Если у вас есть value type `Point`, то

```
Point b = new Point(5, 5);
Point a = b; // скопировали значение b в a
a.X = 1;
Console(b.X) // 5!
```

Переменная reference type хранит в себе ссылку на объект. Для reference type после `a = b` вы получите "`а` ссылается на тот же объект, что и `b`"

```
Point b = new Point(5, 5);
Point a = b; // а теперь указывает (ссылается) на тот же объект Point, что и B
a.X = 1;
Console(b.X) // 1!
```

Это единственное различие.

---

По поводу хранения.

Переменная - это конструкция уровня языка. Переменные не могут "создаваться в динамической памяти".  С точки зрения языка нет разницы между стеком и "динамической памятью".

Стек - это особенность реализации, и компилятор языка сам решает, где хранить значение переменной.

*Значения* переменных могут хранится в стеке или в динамической памяти. Под значением подразумевается непосредственно значение для value type, и ссылка (адрес) - для reference type. Значения *локальных* переменных *обычно* хранятся в стеке.

Но при этом утверждения "переменные value types храняться в стеке" или "переменные с адресом на объект хранятся в стеке, а сами объекты в куче" в принципе неверны.

Смотрите:

1. *Локальная* переменная типа value type. Значение (`5`) скорее всего будет лежать в стеке:

   ```
   int i = 5;
   ```
2. *Локальная* переменная типа reference type. Значение (адрес объекта) скорее всего будет лежать в стеке. Сам объект - в куче.

   ```
   object o = new object();
   ```

Пока вроде сходится?

3. Переменная типа value type - поле класса. Объект вместе со всеми полями лежит в куче. Значение переменной value type (5) лежит .. в куче!

   ```
   class A { public int somefield; } 

   //.....

   A a = new A();
   a.somefield = 5; // положили значение 5 внутрь объекта в куче
   ```
4. *Локальная* переменная типа value type, на которую есть замыкание (упоминание переменной внутри анонимного метода). Объявление ничем не отличается от (1), это точно такая же локальная переменная типа `int`. Но замыкание создает анонимный класс, и переменная на самом деле будет храниться как поле класса. В куче:

   ```
   int i = 5;

   // чуть ниже в том же методе

   Action someAction = () => { Console.WriteLine(i); };
   ```

Так что если взять цитату из книги (насколько я понял, это "Microsoft Visual C#. Подробное руководство"), и разобрать по частям, то:

> Все переменные типов значений создаются в стеке.

Неверно, см. 3 и 4 выше!

> Все переменные ссылочных типов (объекты) создаются в динамической памяти (хотя сами ссылки находятся в стеке)

Неверно, переменная ссылочного типа != объект.

> Типы, допускающие пустые значения, фактически являются ссылочными типами, и переменные этих типов создаются в динамической памяти.

Неверно, речь о nullable types (например, `int?`), а они - структуры, value types. Локальные переменные типа `int?` в случае (1) лежат прямо в стеке - по сути, в стеке лежит структура, в которой одно поле - это флаг "есть ли значение", а второе - само значение.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень понятно объяснили.